# Read Kafka topic tail in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to subscribe to Kafka topic `latest` offset, read some newest records, print them and finish. How can I do this in Spark? I suppose I could do something like this

```
sqlContext
    .read
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.1.1:9092,...")
    .option("subscribe", "myTopic")
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .filter($"someField" === "someValue")
    .take(10)
    .show
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware in advance until which offsets in which partitions you want to consume from Kafka. If you have that information, you can do something like:

```scala
// Subscribe to multiple topics, specifying explicit Kafka offsets
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.1.1:9092,...")
  .option("subscribe", "myTopic")
  .option("startingOffsets", """{"myTopic":{"0":20,"1":20}}""")
  .option("endingOffsets", """{"myTopic":{"0":25,"1":25}}""")
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
  .filter(...)
```

More details on the `startingOffsets` and `endingOffsets` are given in the [Kafka + Spark Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

Comment: No, I don't have any information about offsets. I'd like to just read `n` from the very `latest` in all partitions.

Comment: Okay, but be aware of the following note in the documentation: "For batch queries, latest (either implicitly or by using -1 in json) is not allowed."